# Vim неправильная работа в режиме директории

Tags: vim

При работе в режме директории от vim (мною) ожидается такое поведение:

- Ввел имя директори `vim Documents/`
- Выбрал нужный файл `Enter`
- Отредактировал, вышел (`:wq` или `:q`)
- После выхода снова попал в меню директории
  Однако мой vim работает по другому в 4-ом пункте, после выхода из файла он попадает не в меню выбора директории, а сразу в терминал, и мне снова приходится выбирать директорию (1 пункт). Что мне нужно прописать в конфиге, что бы он работал так, как требуется?

---

Смотрел на многих канал по програмированию, что их vim работает так, как мне нужно

Comment: «*Смотрел на многих канал по програмированию, что их vim работает так, как мне нужно*» — такие заявления лучше подкреплять ссылкой...

Comment: Например [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wl9VX5JXOQ)

Comment: можно таймкод, чтобы все 2 с лишним часа не просматривать?

Comment: Ну он там постоянно пользуется vim, куча случаев, если нужен конкретный то вот

Comment: Например 32 10, он прописал :q,  vim вышел в редим выбора файла.

Comment: Он там похоже табами пользуется (видно вверху слева). Посмотрите на https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13344
Если кратко, то заходить в файл не `Enter`-ом, а буквой `t`, тогда файл открывается в новом табе. Ну или наверняка можно настроить что бы он так по умолчанию открывал.

Comment: Так и есть - табы, видно например на 11:26

Comment: нуда... табы...

Answer (score 1):

Команды `:w`, `:wq` и им подобные всегда закрывают текущее *окно* (см. `:h windows.txt` по поводу разницы между окнами и буферами). Если данное окно хочется использовать в дальнейшем, то это <strike>не те дроиды, которых вы ищете</strike>.

Чтобы открыть в текущем окне предыдущий буфер (см. `:h alternate-file`), как правило, достаточно нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>^</kbd>, ну или ввести команду `:e#`, или сразу `:e Documents` и т.п.